# Hibernate Many To Many Relationship - Data is not fetched for many to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring boot and hibernate. I am creating a simple project with a micro services architecture. While creating entities I've faced a problem with many to many relationship, I've searched whole internet and I couldn't find the answer so maybe someone here can help me. I am using postgres 15 database if it help somehow. spring-boot-jpa version: 3.1, hibernate version: 6.2.2.Final.

I have two entities - `Restaurant` and `Category`:

```
package food.domain.entity;

import food.infrastructure.hibernate.UUIDConverter;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "food_category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Restaurant> restaurants = new HashSet<>();

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Long id, String name, String description, Set<Restaurant> restaurants) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.restaurants = restaurants;
    }

    public void addRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        restaurants.add(restaurant);
    }

}
package food.domain.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "food_restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String openingTime;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String closingTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "food_restaurant_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();


    public Restaurant() {
    }
//
    public Restaurant(Long id, @NonNull String name, String description, @NonNull String openingTime, @NonNull String closingTime, Set<Course> courses, Set<Category> categories) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.openingTime = openingTime;
        this.closingTime = closingTime;
        this.courses = courses;
        this.categories = categories;
    }


    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        this.categories.add(category);
        category.getRestaurants().add(this);
    }

}
```

For linking restaurant with category it works pretty well(from the restaurant side -  that what i wanted to achive)I can see the results in the pivot

```
package food.domain.command.restaurant.create;

import commons.cqrs.command.CommandHandler;
import food.application.response.RestaurantIdResponse;
import food.domain.entity.Restaurant;
import food.infrastructure.repository.CategoryRepository;
import food.infrastructure.repository.RestaurantRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.UUID;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CreateRestaurantCommandHandler implements CommandHandler<RestaurantIdResponse, CreateRestaurantCommand> {

    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    private final RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;

    @Override
    public RestaurantIdResponse handle(CreateRestaurantCommand command) {
        var request = command.request();
        var categories = new HashSet<>(categoryRepository.findAllById(request.categories()));
        var restaurant = Restaurant.builder()
                .name(request.name())
                .description(request.description())
                .openingTime(request.openingTime())
                .closingTime(request.closingTime())
                .categories(categories)
                .build();

        restaurantRepository.save(restaurant);

        return new RestaurantIdResponse(restaurant.getId());
    }
}
```

But when it comes to reading it doesnt work, every time i've got empty set

```
package food.domain.query.restaurant.get;

import commons.cqrs.query.QueryHandler;
import food.application.response.GetRestaurantResponse;
import food.domain.entity.Category;
import food.domain.entity.Restaurant;
import food.domain.exception.RestaurantNotFoundException;
import food.infrastructure.repository.CategoryRepository;
import food.infrastructure.repository.RestaurantRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class GetRestaurantQueryHandler implements QueryHandler<GetRestaurantResponse, GetRestaurantQuery> {

    private final RestaurantRepository repository;
    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Override
    public GetRestaurantResponse handle(GetRestaurantQuery query) {
        Restaurant restaurant = repository.findById(query.restaurantId()).orElseThrow(() -> new RestaurantNotFoundException("Restaurant with id: " + query.restaurantId() + " not found"));

        int z = restaurant.getCategories().size(); // This will trigger the loading of categories from the database
        List<Restaurant> all = repository.findAll();
        Optional<Category> byId = categoryRepository.findById(1L);


        Set<String> categories = restaurant.getCategories().stream().map(Category::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet());


        return new GetRestaurantResponse(
                restaurant.getId(),
                restaurant.getName(),
                restaurant.getDescription(),
                restaurant.getOpeningTime(),
                restaurant.getClosingTime(),
                categories
        );
    }
}
```

Here are also all queries that in executed from GetRestaurantQueryHandler:

```
2023-07-20T17:37:06.730+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.id,r1_0.closing_time,r1_0.description,r1_0.name,r1_0.opening_time from food_restaurant r1_0
2023-07-20T17:37:06.742+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from food_restaurant_category c1_0 join food_category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:06.743+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [9]
2023-07-20T17:37:06.748+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from food_restaurant_category c1_0 join food_category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:06.749+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.858+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.id,c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.description,c1_1.name,r1_0.closing_time,r1_0.description,r1_0.name,r1_0.opening_time from food_restaurant r1_0 left join (food_restaurant_category c1_0 join food_category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.category_id) on r1_0.id=c1_0.restaurant_id where r1_0.id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.860+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [7]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.868+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.category_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.closing_time,r1_1.description,r1_1.name,r1_1.opening_time from food_restaurant_category r1_0 join food_restaurant r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.restaurant_id where r1_0.category_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.870+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.878+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.availability,c2_0.id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,r1_0.category_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.closing_time,r1_1.description,r1_1.name,r1_1.opening_time,c1_0.cost,c1_0.description,c1_0.name from food_food c1_0 left join food_category c2_0 on c2_0.id=c1_0.category_id left join (food_restaurant_category r1_0 join food_restaurant r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.restaurant_id) on c2_0.id=r1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.879+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.885+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from food_restaurant_category c1_0 join food_category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.886+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.893+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.category_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.closing_time,r1_1.description,r1_1.name,r1_1.opening_time from food_restaurant_category r1_0 join food_restaurant r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.restaurant_id where r1_0.category_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.895+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.901+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.availability,c2_0.id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,r1_0.category_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.closing_time,r1_1.description,r1_1.name,r1_1.opening_time,c1_0.cost,c1_0.description,c1_0.name from food_food c1_0 left join food_category c2_0 on c2_0.id=c1_0.category_id left join (food_restaurant_category r1_0 join food_restaurant r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.restaurant_id) on c2_0.id=r1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.902+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [6]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.908+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from food_restaurant_category c1_0 join food_category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.909+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [6]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.914+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.availability,c2_0.id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,r1_0.category_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.closing_time,r1_1.description,r1_1.name,r1_1.opening_time,c1_0.cost,c1_0.description,c1_0.name from food_food c1_0 left join food_category c2_0 on c2_0.id=c1_0.category_id left join (food_restaurant_category r1_0 join food_restaurant r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.restaurant_id) on c2_0.id=r1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.915+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [7]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.919+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from food_restaurant_category c1_0 join food_category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.920+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [7]
2023-07-20T17:37:37.925+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.category_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.closing_time,r1_1.description,r1_1.name,r1_1.opening_time from food_restaurant_category r1_0 join food_restaurant r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.restaurant_id where r1_0.category_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:37.926+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
2023-07-20T17:37:56.784+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.id,r1_0.closing_time,r1_0.description,r1_0.name,r1_0.opening_time from food_restaurant r1_0
2023-07-20T17:37:56.799+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from food_restaurant_category c1_0 join food_category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:56.800+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [9]
2023-07-20T17:37:56.807+02:00 DEBUG 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.restaurant_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from food_restaurant_category c1_0 join food_category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.category_id where c1_0.restaurant_id=?
2023-07-20T17:37:56.808+02:00 TRACE 61831 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4]
```

In `GetRestaurantQueryHandler`, 'z','all', 'byId' objects are just debugging ones. `Restaurant` object doesn't contain any category, but the `byId` object contains  this restaurant... So I've tried to reverse the mapping, so maybe then I will got any categories in the restaurant object but nothing really changed. In the beginning I was using UUID instead of Long, I read that it maybe because the issue but unfortunately not. I also tried to remove new `HashSet<>()` from definition, remove `JoinTable`, create pivot entity, nothing worked... Do you have any idea why it works like this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBxdv.png)